# Can't open android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have a working Android project here: https://github.com/hanchang/Friar-Framework.
I am a total newbie in Eclipse.
Do you have any idea how to open this project?

Comment: unzip the file you are downloaded then import that file into your eclipse.

Comment: at what point are you stuck? what error do you get? what exactly is your difficulty? please, provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

Go to `File->Import` option in Eclipse

Comment: The tricky thing about Eclipse is that it's workspace based, rather than being a simple file based system.  If you don't go to the extra step of "importing", things are just invisible.  Trips up many a newbie, provided me with a couple hours of frustration at first too!

Answer (score 0):

File-> import> existing projects into work space>select the root folder of the unzipped project which you downloaded.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you! I will let you know if it helps!